# Where is the ToObservable extension method?

Tags: .net, system.reactive

I see it mentioned [here](http://themechanicalbride.blogspot.com/2009/07/introducing-rx-linq-to-events.html), but I can't work out which `using` I have to add to get it.

(Rolled my own for the moment)

Comment: What's weird is that I do see IObservable and IObserver...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add reference to System.Reactive.dll. Then in code write:

```
using System.Linq;
```

UPDATE:
Now Rx is available as separate extensions. There are 3 versions of Rx: Rx for .NET 3.5 Sp1, Rx for Silverlight 3 and Rx for .NET 4 Beta 2. All 3 versions can be downloaded from the [Devlabs Rx project page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896.aspx).

Comment: And where do I get System.Reactive.dll?

Comment: Found it: download Silverlight Toolkit source (http://silverlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/ListDownloadableCommits.aspx), then get it out of the binaries...

Comment: Download Silverlight Toolkit here: http://silverlight.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=30514
Then add reference to System.Reactive.dll (by default - C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v3.0\Toolkit\Oct09\Bin)

Comment: But then I get a conflict with System.Collections.Generic.IObservable - interesting...

Comment: I used it - no conflicts, everything works ok. Do you use VS 2010 beta2 or 2008 ?

Comment: I was in VS2010 beta2, now I've downloaded 3.5 version and using it in 2008... fun fun fun!

Comment: Download this sample application - http://amazedsaint.blogspot.com/2009/11/linq-to-events-more-on-net-reactive.html

Comment: Marking as answer, if you take it with the comments.

Answer (score 14):

It is in:

```
using System.Reactive.Linq;
```

Comment: once you have added a reference to System.Reactive, then this (using System.Reactive.Linq;) is the correct using statement for ToObservable, not System.Linq..

Answer (score 0):

You need install Nuget-package System.Reactive.Linq